# Why is Twitter showing me old Tweets much more often past few days and what can I do with it?

Tags: twitter

For the last week or so, I am noticing, that about half of my Timeline is older than a day. Very often it is more than two or even more too. **I am sure, that this didn't happen before.**

However, I didn't find any news about this change, only recent news is about *original tweeter* ([NBC for example](https://www.nbcnews.com/business/business-news/twitter-testing-new-way-determine-where-tweet-started-n962426)).

What is the reason? Is there any other change? Or is it a bug? **Can I turn it back in some settings?**

Comment: why the -1, please? can I improve somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has made some changes about showing **top Tweets** first and the **latest Tweets** first recently.

By default it shows top Tweets first, because of that you are seeing old Tweets first on your Timeline. You need to change that setting:

1. Open up [Twitter](https://twitter.com)
2. Go to **Settings and Privacy**
3. Go to **Account**
4. Scroll down to *Timeline Show the best Tweets first* in **Content** section
5. Un-check that box

[image]

If you are on mobile using iOS or Android, you can change this setting by doing following:

[image]

About the announcement of these changes you can follow [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Twitter) and [Twitter Support](https://twitter.com/TwitterSupport) handles. Below are few status you can see:

https://twitter.com/TwitterSupport/status/1041838954008391680
https://twitter.com/TwitterSupport/status/1042155714205016064
https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1075074100412985345

Comment: X no longer allows that change, I guess we're stuck with day old tweets.